# WordPress theme in OOP

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I want to develop a WordPress Theme using Object Oriented Programming (OOP).
I have searched a lot. But I didn't found any way to do this.

Please tell the proper way, how can I develop WordPress theme using OOP.

Answer (score -2):

If by OOP, you mean classes in PHP, then yeah you can do a lot of that in OOP. Instead of using functions like `get_the_content()`, you can use the `$post` object to grab the content, for example.